# plotly dash: create multiple callbacks (with loop?)

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Say I have a model with 20 parameters and I made one input component for each param.

```
[dcc.Input(type = 'number', id = 'input %i'%i) for i in range(20)]
```

I want to have one button `html.Button('populate parameters', id = 'button populate')` that is supposed to populate best pre-fitted value for all the inputs.

Code should look like below, except it doesn't work.

```
for i in range(20):
    @app.callback(
        dash.dependencies.Output('input %i'%i, 'value'),
        [dash.dependencies.Input('button populate', 'n_clicks')]
    )
    def update(ignore):
        return np.random.uniform()
```

Do I have to write 20 callbacks for each output with identical functionality? I can't find a way to make them in one go (loop?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have dealt with the same issue and found a solution. What you do is bypass the decorator and call the `app.callback` function directly:

```
def update(ignore):
    return np.random.uniform()

for i in range(20):
    app.callback(
        dash.dependencies.Output('input %i' % i, 'value'),
        [dash.dependencies.Input('button populate', 'n_clicks')]
    )(update)
```

Answer (score 8):

In [dash >= 1.11.0](https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-v1-11-0-release-introducing-pattern-matching-callbacks/37592) you may use [Pattern-Matching Callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks). No loops needed when defining the callback(s).

### Example

#### 1. Import callback selectors

- Import `dash.dependecies.ALL`:

```py
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State, ALL
```

- Other available callback selectors are `MATCH` and `ALLSMALLER`.

#### 2. Use dictionaries as the `id`

- Define your components with a `id` that is a **dictionary**. You may choose any keys but for example `type` and `id` are quite reasonable choices. So, instead of

```py
[dcc.Input(type = 'number', id = 'input %i'%i) for i in range(20)]
```

use

```py
[
    dcc.Input(type='number',
              id={
                  'type': 'my-input-type',
                  'id': 'input %i' % i
              }) for i in range(20)
]
```

#### 3. Use a callback selector with `@app.callback`

- Use the `ALL` callback selector when defining the callback:

```py
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output({
        'type': 'my-input-type',
        'id': ALL
    }, 'value'), [dash.dependencies.Input('button populate', 'n_clicks')])
def update(ignore):
    return np.random.uniform()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar to populate my layout component after page reload.

Thanks to the first callback, the state of the components are store in a dcc.Store component. 
The second callback is to populate the layout components when their state changes or when you access the tab ( the layout is in a dcc.Tabs)

```
dash_layout_components = {
'time_slider_app2': 'value',
'backtest_choice_app2': 'values',
'asset_selection_app2': 'value',
'graph_selection_app2': 'values'
}

stored_layout_value_name = [key[:key.rfind('a')] + value for key, value in 
dash_layout_components.items()]

set_back_and_display_graph_input = {
    'store_layout_data': 'modified_timestamp',
    'tabs': 'value'
}


@app.callback(
Output('store_layout_data', 'data'),
[Input(key, value) for key, value in dash_layout_components.items()])
def store_layout(time_slider_value, backtest_choice_values, assets_selection_values, graph_selection_values):

    data_json = {
        'time_slider_value': time_slider_value,
        'backtest_choice_values': backtest_choice_values,
        'asset_selection_value': assets_selection_values,
        'graph_selection_values': graph_selection_values
   }
   return data_json


for component_id, component_property in dash_layout_components.items():
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id, component_property),
    [Input(key, value) for key, value in set_back_and_display_graph_input.items()],
    [State('store_layout_data', 'data'),
     State(component_id, 'id')]
)
def set_back_component(bouton_ts, tabs_value, layout_state_data, component):  # dynamiser l'arrivée des paramètres. piste, en créer une liste entre le for et le callback

    if tabs_value != '/app2':
        raise PreventUpdate

    if layout_state_data is None:
        return []

    else:
        store_layout_component_name = stored_layout_value_name[list(dash_layout_components.keys()).index(component)]
        return layout_state_data[store_layout_component_name]
```

Note that you won't have access to the iterated values (component_id and component_property) inside the function ( set_back_component(...) )

Answer (score 0):

you can have as many input parameters/argument on a callback as you want.
But only **one output**.

What solved a similar case for me was:

```
@app.callback(
    [Output('output-id', 'children')],
    [Input('button-trigger', 'n_clicks'],
    [State('input-one', 'value'),
    ...
    [State('input-twenty', 'value')]
)
def my_fancy_function(n_clicks, v1, ..., v20):
    return sth_awesome
```

`State()` as opposed to `Input()` does not trigger the callback when an input value is changed.

`n_clicks` changes +1 with each click but doesn't need to be used.

If your parameters are dependent on each other you would need more callbacks.
But...with 20 parameters `There must be a better way`

Comment: Hi thanks. I edited my question to make it clearer what I want. The *one output* constraint is the issue here. I have one input but 20 outputs.

Comment: had a similiar issue for that too: I dumped the results as ``json`` into a hidden ``Div`` s  ``children`` property and read that particular ``Div`` with 5 callbacks.
That approach left the callbacks quite 'simple' since all calbacks would listen to to that ``Div``.