# Return ‘href’ value on a click event in Python Dash

Tags: python, python-3.x, href, plotly-dash

I have been trying to return the ‘href’ value from click event in python-Dash application. Below is my code snippet:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State


app = dash.Dash(
    __name__,
    meta_tags=[{"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}],
)


def make_table(df, val):
    table = []

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        rows = []
        html.Td([
                    html.Div([row["col1"]]),
                    html.A(id = 'link',href=row["file-link"], children=row["link-name"], target="_blank"),
                  ])
        table.append(html.Tr(rows))

    return table


app.layout = html.Div([
                        html.Table(
                            id="table-element",
                            className="table__container",
                        )
                        ],
                        className="six columns",
                        ),


@app.callback(
    Output("link", 'pathname'),
    [Input('link', 'n_clicks')],
    [State('link', 'href')]
    )
def open_link(n_clicks, href):
    enable_open_link(href) #enable_open_link function takes in the href string value (a local filesystem link) and opens it up in a new window.


@app.callback(
    Output("table-element", 'children'),
    [Input("input-1-submit", 'n_submit')],
     [State('input-1-submit', 'value')]
)
def update_output(ns1,val):
    table = make_table(df,val)
    
    return table
```

This code works upto some extent i.e. it does returns a href value, but not the one I click. It always returns the last href value stored inside the html table.

Is there a way to fetch the href value when I click on the link?
I know I can use Jquery to fetch the correct href value… but I didn’t find a way to integrate javascript within the call-back function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a clue from thread provided by @Rudertier, I was able to get the solution.
Below is the updated code snippet:

```
def make_table(df, val):
    table = []

    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        rows = []
        html.Td([
                    html.Div([row["col1"]]),
                    html.A(id = 'link'+str(index),href=row["file-link"], children=row["link-name"], target="_blank"),
                  ])
        table.append(html.Tr(rows))

    return table


app.layout = html.Div([
                        html.Table(
                            id="table-element",
                            className="table__container",
                        )
                        ],
                        className="six columns",
                        ),


links = ['link1','link2','link3','link4','link5','link6','link7','link8','link9','link10']   
for link in links: 
    @app.callback(
        Output('{}'.format(link), 'pathname'),
        [Input('{}'.format(link), 'n_clicks')],
        [State('{}'.format(link), 'href')]
        )
    def open_link(n_clicks, href):
        enable_open_link(href) #enable_open_link function takes in the href string value (a local filesystem link) and opens it up in a new window.


@app.callback(
    Output("table-element", 'children'),
    [Input("input-1-submit", 'n_submit')],
     [State('input-1-submit', 'value')]
)
def update_output(ns1,val):
    table = make_table(df,val)
    
    return table
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because all the links you'r creating have the same `id ='link'`.

You'll need to find a way around that. One possibilty would be to generate the `id` when creating it based on the index of your df, but then you'll also have to create the corresponding callbacks. This thread tells you how it could be done. [plotly dash: create multiple callbacks (with loop?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917648/plotly-dash-create-multiple-callbacks-with-loop)

Comment: Hey Rud, thanks! it worked. tbh I tried running it with multiple callbacks but was providing the 'link' as an input component_id with component_property "n_clicks" instead of assigning the id dynamically.