# Python Dash Callback Looping

Tags: python, loops, dynamic, callback, plotly-dash

I try to learn Python Dash to visualize some data. I worked on the Plotly Example with multiple Buttons:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Button 1', id='btn-nclicks-1', n_clicks=0),
    html.Button('Button 2', id='btn-nclicks-2', n_clicks=0),
    html.Button('Button 3', id='btn-nclicks-3', n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='container-button-timestamp')
   ])

@app.callback(Output('container-button-timestamp', 'children'),
          Input('btn-nclicks-1', 'n_clicks'),
          Input('btn-nclicks-2', 'n_clicks'),
          Input('btn-nclicks-3', 'n_clicks'))
def displayClick(btn1, btn2, btn3):
    changed_id = [p['prop_id'] for p in dash.callback_context.triggered][0]
    if 'btn-nclicks-1' in changed_id:
        msg = 'Button 1 was most recently clicked'
    elif 'btn-nclicks-2' in changed_id:
        msg = 'Button 2 was most recently clicked'
    elif 'btn-nclicks-3' in changed_id:
        msg = 'Button 3 was most recently clicked'
    else:
        msg = 'None of the buttons have been clicked yet'
    return html.Div(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The code displays which button was clicked recently. I want to ask if it is possible to put this in a loop, so that I can loop over i numbers of buttons, because it is pretty much work if I want to use 50 buttons or so.

Instead of

```
html.Button('Button 1', id='btn-nclicks-1', n_clicks=0),
html.Button('Button 2', id='btn-nclicks-2', n_clicks=0),
html.Button('Button 3', id='btn-nclicks-3', n_clicks=0),
```

something like:

```
for i in range(number_buttons):
    html.Button('Button i', id='btn-nclicks-i', n_clicks=0)

@app.callback(
    Input('btn-nclicks-i', 'n_clicks')
)
```

I'd appreciate some links to tutorials or examples with Dash Callbacks.

Comment: This link may be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917648/plotly-dash-create-multiple-callbacks-with-loop

Answer (score 1):

The trickiest part about this is adding all of the buttons created in your loop as `Input` to your `callback`, but you can do that using pattern matching callbacks (see [dash docs](https://dash.plotly.com/pattern-matching-callbacks)). Here is a small example, using the code you provided as basis but using 10 buttons via a loop:

```
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, ALL
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

btnlst = [html.Button(
              'Button {}'.format(i),
               id={
                   'type' : 'mybuttons',
                   'index' : i,
               }
         )
         for i in range(10)]

app.layout = html.Div(btnlst + [
    html.Div(id='btn-out-container'),
])

@app.callback(Output('btn-out-container', 'children'),
                Input({'type':'mybuttons', 'index':ALL}, 'n_clicks'))
def display_click(nclicks):
    changed_id = [p['prop_id'] for p in dash.callback_context.triggered][0]
    if changed_id == '.':
        msg = 'None of the buttons have been clicked yet'
    else:
        # do additional parsing of changed_id here as necessary
        msg = 'Changed property: {}'.format(changed_id)
    return html.Div(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Important things to note:

- I created the list of buttons `btnlst` beforehand and added it to the first argument of the other `html.Div` component. That technique is universal and does not only work with pattern matching callbacks.
- Note the form of the `id` property of each button, which is needed to use them in a pattern matching callback. The `type` of the `id` can be any string, but if you are going to use multiple groups like this, it's advisable to not mix their names.
- The `changed_id` used in `display_clicks` has a pretty custom format, as you can see when looking at the output. You'll propably need to do some extra parsing on it, especially if you have any other `Input` besides just the list of buttons.